# Nested variables in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

I have a problem with twig. I need to use nested variables such as (account is an object)

```
{{ likes_array.[account.idOnSn].lifetime }}
```

This is a result of print_r(likes_array)

```
array(2) {
    ["tanitweb"]=> array(2) {
        ["lifetime"]=> int(1420)
        ["daily"]=> int(0)
    }
    ["fstjuniorentreprise"]=> array(2) {
        ["lifetime"]=> int(3310)
        ["daily"]=> int(3310)
    }
}
```

I get this exception

> Expected name or number in StatsDotTnMainBundle:Default:acceuil.php.twig at line 188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use index notation, with square brackets:

```
{{ likes_array[account.idOnSn].lifetime }}
```

Comment: @Everblack Can you provide more information about your variables, like the output of a print_r or vardump? Put it in your question, please, and not in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Everblack can you clarify further? I don't see where you are setting `likes_array`, `account`, or `account.idOnSn`, and it's not clear what in your array corresponds to those variables

Comment: @Everblack Glad I could help!